# Given contraction in $\|\cdot \|_2$ norm, what is the contraction in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm?

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions, contraction-operator

Suppose that I have a contraction $f$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$

$$\|f(x) - f(y)\|_2 \leq l\|x-y\|_2, l\in[0,1)$$

What can I say about $k>0$

$$\|f(x) - f(y)\|_\infty \leq k\|x-y\|_\infty$$

What about any $1\leq p \leq \infty$ norm?

$$\|f(x) - f(y)\|_p \leq k\|x-y\|_p$$

Comment: See [this](http://planetmath.org/EquivalentNorms). Now check if the $p$-norms are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent: there exist $c_p,C_p>0$ such that

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\quad c_p\|x\|_p\leq\|x\|_2\leq C_p\|x\|_p$.

This yields $c_p\|f(x)-f(y)\|_p\leq lC_p\|x-y\|_p$ and therefore $\|f(x)-f(y)\|_p\leq l\frac{C_p}{c_p}\|x-y\|_p$.

Comment: How to go about finding $C_p$ and $c_p$ for infinity norm? Are these results well known?

Comment: So it might be a contraction and it might not be a contraction depending on the value of $lC_p/c_p$. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know the values of $c_p$ and $C_p$ (of course one should use the best possible constants) for any $p$. But I'm pretty sure they are known. It is easy to see that $c_\infty=1$ and $C_\infty=\sqrt{n}$.